# My Retrofit call.enque() method is getting skipped over entirely, not sure why

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit

I'm making a call using Retrofit's `enqueue()` method. I'm calling my `refreshImages()` in my MainActivity's `onCreate()`, `refreshImages()` then calls a method `refreshImagesIds()` which is supposed to make a call out to Flickr's API and return back a `PhotosList` object, I'll then pull out the `Photos` from there which will contain a list of `Photo` objects. My issue is that for some reason the `onResponse()` inside my `enqueue()` method is never getting called. When I use the debugger it skips right over it, and when I put Log statements inside they never get written out. I know the endpoint it is hitting is correct because I can see it using OkHttp's logger, and my POJOs all look to be correct for the data being returned.

Any idea why this isn't working? Below are my `refreshImages` and `refreshImagesId`. These are both contained in my MainAcitivty and modify class-level variables.

```
private void refreshImages() {
        // make api call
        //imageUrls = FlickrServiceManager_withinterface.getKittenImages(8);

        refreshImageIds();

        List<Photo> photos = photosList.getPhotos().getPhoto();
        imageIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Photo photo : photos) {
            Log.d("TAG", "It is pringint imageIds: " + photo.getId());
            imageIds.add(photo.getId());
        }
}

private void refreshImageIds() {
    Retrofit retrofit = Api.getRestAdapter();
    FlickrServiceInterface flickrService = retrofit.create(FlickrServiceInterface.class);
    Call<PhotosList> call = flickrService.getPhotos(API_KEY, FORMAT, "1");
    imageIds = new ArrayList<String>();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<PhotosList>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PhotosList> call, Response<PhotosList> response) {
            photosList = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PhotosList> call, Throwable t) {
            // TODO: Clean up
            Log.d("TEMP_TAG", "Call failed");
        }
    });
}
```

And my FlickrServiceInterface:

```
public interface FlickrServiceInterface {

    @GET("?method=flickr.photos.getSizes")
    Call<PhotoSizes> getPhotoSizes(@Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("format") String format, @Query("nojsoncallback") String jsonCallback, @Query("photo_id") String photoId);

    @GET("?method=flickr.photos.getRecent")
    Call<PhotosList> getPhotos(@Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("format") String format, @Query("nojsoncallback") String jsonCallback);
}
```

Comment: The callback is not called synchronously. It's a network call, and it could take a few seconds to complete.

Comment: That may be so, but it seems like I'm never getting a response? `onResponse()` never gets executed, the log statements inside it never get written out to the console.

Comment: @EricCochran how can I make sure the method is waiting for the call to complete? Do I need to synchronize this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Change your call to the synchronous retrofit API :

```
public static List<String> getImageIds(int size) {
    Call<PhotosList> call = flickrService.getPhotos(apiKey, format, "1");
    photoIds = new ArrayList<String>();

    PhotosList photosList = call.execute().body();
    List<Photo> photos = photosList.getPhotos().getPhoto();

    for(Photo photo : photos) {
        Log.d("TEMP_TAG", "adding photo id to list: " + photo.getId());
        photoIds.add(photo.getId());
    }
    Log.d("TEMP_TAG", "it's getting here too");
    return photoIds;
}
```

Please note that you need to call this method on an `AsyncTask`

**EDIT**

You could also continue to use enqueue, but you need to provide an "onFinish" hook, so you know when your data has been received and then you "notify" the client with the data:

```
//interface por communication
public interface ImageIdsCallBack {
   public void onFinish( List<String> photoIds );
}
```

Then you receive this interface and send data:

```
public static List<String> getImageIds(int size, final ImageIdsCallBack callback) {
    Call<PhotosList> call = flickrService.getPhotos(apiKey, format, "1");
    photoIds = new ArrayList<String>();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<PhotosList>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PhotosList> call, Response<PhotosList> response) {
            PhotosList photosList = response.body();
            List<Photo> photos = photosList.getPhotos().getPhoto();

            for(Photo photo : photos) {
                Log.d("TEMP_TAG", "adding photo id to list: " + photo.getId());
                photoIds.add(photo.getId());
            }
            //send the data to the caller
            callback.onFinish(photoIds);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PhotosList> call, Throwable t) {
            // TODO: Clean up
            Log.d("TEMP_TAG", "Call failed");
        }
    });
    Log.d("TEMP_TAG", "it's getting here too");
    return photoIds;
}
```

calling the method :

```
getImageIds( 50 , new ImageIdsCallBack() {
     public void onFinish( List<String> photoIds ) {
         //update UI with photoIds
     }
} );
```

I typically use a library like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to make it easier, I really recommend it to you.

Comment: Ok, cool. But I'm wondering why I would need to do this? I've used `enqueue()` plenty of times in other apps with no issue. Is there something about the way I've structured this to make it require a synchronous call? I'd like to stick with `enqueue()` so I could change my implementation to better suit that if so.

Comment: Is it because my methods are static? If I were to change everything to instance methods and instantiate my `FlickrServiceManager` inside of my `MainActivity` or where ever I need the API data, would `enqueue()` work then?

Comment: The problem is you are trying to obtain your data before the network call is over, I will edit my answer with an alternative to use enqueue

Comment: Interesting, thank you for this. I will try it now. Still a bit confused because I've definitely modified class level variables using contents of `response.Body()` within `onResponse()` in the past and it's worked just fine. Maybe because those were much smaller responses that didn't take as long to execute?

Comment: The problem is not the modification of the variables, but what you do with them, if you try to access the variables just after calling you API it won't work, but if you modified and accessed them later on, it's a race condition.

Comment: I've modified the method parameters if you look carefully

Comment: Hmm, getting an error on `callback.onFinish(photoIds)` saying that the variable is being accessed from an inner class and needs to be declared final. I guess it's alright for me to pass it in as a final variable?

Comment: Ok, unfortunately this still isn't working for me. I know I haven't updated the `getImageUrl()` method to use this onFinish hook, but it is still not even getting into the `onResponse()` of `getImageIds()` . I also tried putting a log statement in my implemented `onFinish()` method and it never printed. I updated my post with the new code. It looks pretty much identical to yours.

Comment: It's at the top, in the first method `getKittenImages(int)`. Basically I want other Activitys in my app to be able to just call `FlickrServiceManager.getKittenImages(int)` and get back a list of strings containing the URLs to different images.

Comment: You need to call the getImagedId on the activity, otherwise you are doing the same

Comment: You're saying I need to call getImageIds from an activity and not from within the same class? I just tried this with the same result, nothing happens. I feel like I'm making this very complicated for myself. I really just need to get some imageIds from one API call and then pass them in one-by-one to another API call to get their URLs, then pass those URLs to an Activity. Would really only like to use Retrofit without any other libraries right now.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, is this on the main thread? That would pose the problem of not waiting for a response.

Consider using `async`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if it helps but I thought my call.enqueue() is getting skipped but I didn't handle the response i was getting I was getting a 400 response. So I would suggest to log the response code you are getting. hope it helps someone.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback < LoginResponse > () {
     @ Override
    public void onResponse(Call < LoginResponse > call, Response < LoginResponse > response) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Response code " + response.code());
        if (response.code() == 200) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Going into Login page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        /*if(response.code()==400){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error 400", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }* added it later after I saw in debugging that I am getting
        400 error because I was using email instead of username */
    }
     @ Override
    public void onFailure(Call < LoginResponse > call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
    }
});
}
});
```